# Как понять какой алгоритм вычисления чек суммы используется?

Tags: алгоритм

Работаю через COM порт с контроллером, который принимает определенные параметры в виде этих двух строчек. Моя задача - генерировать подобные строки с нужными параметрами.

23 первых байта отвечают за хранения параметров, а вот два последних, как мне кажется отвечают за чек сумму (в пером примере это `d5 91`). Проблема в том, что я не могу понять по каким они правилам изменяются. Экспериментальным путём выяснил, что зависят они только от состояния предыдущих байтов, но закономерность явно не линейная. Из алгоритмов пробовал применять вариации CRC, но результатов это никаких не дало.

*Вопрос: можно как-то понять что за алгоритм тут используется?*

Ниже через строчку идут примеры строк с данными.

```
01 10 00 50 00 08 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 d5 91      

01 10 00 50 00 08 10 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 14 91    

01 10 00 50 00 08 10 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 d7 10         

01 10 00 50 00 08 10 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 d1 6d     

01 10 00 50 00 08 10 01 f4 07 da 13 ec 07 e4 27 
0f 00 04 00 00 00 00 6b 92      

01 10 00 60 00 08 10 03 20 03 f2 0b b8 07 e4 0b 
b7 00 04 00 01 00 00 41 23     

01 10 00 e0 00 08 10 01 2c 00 6e 03 e8 07 e4 00 
13 00 03 00 01 00 01 30 a0
```

Comment: это Modbus CRC-16 ([алгоритм на wikibooks](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#CRC-16))

Comment: Спасибо большое, это и правда он. А как вы поняли что использовать нужно именно его?

Comment: повезло. это была первая попавшаяся реализация crc-16, которую я смог скопипастить